# Why this is not working? Strings in C. If always true. WHY?

Tags: c, string, file

Please help me.
I don't know why this program is not working.
Sorry, but I needed to post whole code so it can be understanded clearly.

I tried to put str in txt file and then read it again and it is the same problem.
Also, I tried changing pointers with some other and then sompareing them and also the samo problem.

Arguments of program are:

1) txt file - with something like this - xyxxyyyxyxxyxyyxyxyxyyyyxxxx...

2) number - example - 2 - means that i need to group symbols in pairs

Output should be probaillity of any combination of x and y (xx,yy,xy,yx - for group of 2).
example:

```
p(xx)=0.4
p(yy)=0.1
p(yx)=0.5
p(xy)=0
```

BUT!
this is ALWAYS TRUE:

```
 if (str==lista[i])
```

WHY?
I am struggling with it for hours. :(

I tried what others suggested:

Look at this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qtur.jpg   and
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk6wA.jpg

Weirdest one:

```
http://i.imgur.com/BIeLXOu.gif
```

WHOLE CODE:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef char * string;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
if (argc<3) {
    return -1;
}

FILE *ul;
int mode,i,dane,j,razl;
char *str;
int brojac=0;
string lista[1000];
int   pomlis[1000];
ul=fopen(argv[1],"r");
fseek(ul,0,SEEK_SET);

if (!ul){
    return 1;
}
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    lista[i]="nist";
    pomlis[i]=0;
}
mode=atoi(argv[2]);
str=(char*)malloc(mode+1);
brojac=0;   
razl=0;

while (fgets(str,sizeof(char)*mode+1,ul)!=NULL){

    dane=0;
//  printf("%s ",str);  //da bi printao u konzolu

    brojac++;
    for (i=0;i<=razl;i++){  
        if (str==lista[i]){
            pomlis[i]++; 
            dane=1;
        }
    }

    if (dane==0){
        if (lista[i]=="nist") i--; 
        lista[i+1]=str; 
        pomlis[i+1]=1;
        razl++; 
    }
}
for (i=1;i<=razl;i++){
    printf("p(%s)=%f\n",lista[i],pomlis[i]/((double)brojac));
}

fclose(ul);

return 0;
}
```

I tried all suggestions in the comments and nothing works. Does anyone knows the answer?

Comment: If you are trying to compare equality of the strings themselves you need strcmp

Comment: Edited. Do you know what is the problem with if? Look at the images i added.

Comment: There is no problem with if. Your debugging is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of, sizeof(char) is 1 *by definition*. It doesn't make the code more readable.

The line

> fgets(str,sizeof(char)*mode+1,ul);

reads into char *str which is allocated in

> str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*mode);

Which should omit the cast, and is too small to hold everything fgets() writes to it (by the +1 '\0').

In addition:

> printf("p(%s)=%d\n",lista[i],pomlis[i]/brojac);

pomolis[i] and brojac are both integers, therefore the division will not return a fraction (float/double) but an integer again (most likely zero in your program).

> Thank you all, edited, but, can I get answer? Why I am getting minuses on question if no one knows answer?

Well, try replacing the line

> ```
>    if (str==lista[i]){
> ```

with

> if (!strncmp(str, &lista[i], mode){

and remove the line

> ```
> fgets(str,sizeof(char)*mode+1,ul);
> ```

in the body of the while-loop (you are already calling fgets() in the while condition, don't call it twice)

Comment: `First of, sizeof(char) is 1 by definition`. No it is not. `char` is `At least 1 byte`. On some systems, as weird as it may be, `char` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Yes, char may contain more than 8 bits. Nevertheless, sizeof(char) will still be 1. It's the other sizeof(data type) that have to change.

Comment: am.. should I even dignify your reply? If the data is 2-bytes wide, sizeof will be 2.

Comment: @bolov sizeof(char) is 1 by definition

Comment: Ok there are two people telling me this so I could be wrong. Could you find in the standard where it is saying this?

Comment: Yes I have found. I am sorry, you are right. Didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you all, edited, but, can I get answer? 
Why I am getting minuses on question if no one knows answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many problems. I suggest reading about pointers, memory allocation and how strings work in c. Because of your `typedef char * string` i suppose you must be coming from a higher language then c. Forget that knowledge, you'll have big problems if you try to apply it here.

I've made it work, but I will not post the working code here, as I'm not interested in doing anyone's homework. I'll try to teach you what your problems are.

Your first problem is here:

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    lista[i]="nist";
    pomlis[i]=0;
}
```

Assigning `"nist"` to `char *` assigns the address of a constant string `"nist"` to the pointer. As the string is constant, if you later try to change something in it, you will fail.

You should use `malloc`, which allocates memory you can write to:

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    lista[i]=(char*) malloc(5);
    pomlis[i]=0;
}
```

Next, as others have explained, using `==` is quite different then using `strncmp`. You should use:

```
if (strcmp(str, lista[i])==0){
    pomlis[i]++;
    dane=1;
}
```

The next part makes absolutely no sense:

```
if (dane==0){
    if (lista[i]=="nist") i--; 
    lista[i+1]=str; 
    pomlis[i+1]=1;
    razl++; 
}
```

First you're comparing to another pointer to constant string (note that `"nist"` you've initialized to doesn't have to be the same `"nist"` you have here). I really have no idea what you're trying to accomplish using `i` here.

I wrote it like this:

```
if (dane==0){
    memcpy(lista[razl],str, sizeof(str));
    pomlis[razl]=1;
    razl++;
}
```

Try to understand this.

Finally, your `for` loops go to the limit `i<=razl`. As arrays are zero initialized, you should break before `i` hits `razl`.

Comment: I know what memcpy do, but can it be without it?

Comment: And also, can you please look at the second image and tell me what is happening there?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str==lista[i])
```

Now, `str` and `lista[i]` are of type `char*`. That is they are pointers. In which case the `==` operator tests for equality of the pointer addresses. So, if this `==` operator evaluates true then the two pointers have the same address.

If you want to compare the value of the string then you must use `strcmp()`.

Comment: There are many other issues with your code but I don't have the energy right now to cover them all. I think this answers the question you asked.

Comment: No dice. When I print them in the if they are different but it enters the if.

Comment: If that `==` evaluates true then the two pointers have the same value. That is the variables `str` and `lista[i]` contain the same address.

Comment: Hm, if the address of them would compare equal, their contents would also, no? So changing to `strcmp` wouldn't change much.

Comment: I tried strcmp, and it is the same. But i added this in the if:   
    printf("%s-%s ",str,lista[i]);
    
And it prints for example:    xx-nist

Comment: Then both == and strcmp will indicate those strings are not equal. Note that strcmp does that by returning a non-zero value.

Comment: Just copy my code and try it. Why it evaluates always true? O.o

Comment: Your == evaluates true if and only if the two pointer operands have the same value

Comment: Look at this:
1:[first image](http://i.imgur.com/SL1L8hc.jpg) 
2:[second image](http://i.imgur.com/QwZGdgM.jpg) 
3:[third image](http://i.imgur.com/BIeLXOu.gif) 

WIERD

Comment: Your images make no sense to me. You use strcmp wrong. Read the docs, and my comments to learn why. Everything I said in my answer is accurate. Why can't you see that == means the two pointers have the same value?